# Flyway 4.2.0 Multiple Nodes In Parallel Failure with Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle11g, flyway

I have multiple application servers configured to run flyway at startup.  Each server attempts to apply the same set of migrations across multiple schemas in the same Oracle 11g database. These servers are started at the same time.  This works most of the time.  On occasion, however, a server fails during migration because it encounters a unique constraint violation.

Unable to insert row for version '0' in metadata table "FOO"."SCHEMA_VERSION"

SQL State  : 23000
Error Code : 1
Message    : ORA-00001: unique constraint (FOO.SCHEMA_VERSION_pk) violated

```
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.addAppliedMigration(MetaDataTableImpl.java:242)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.addBaselineMarker(MetaDataTableImpl.java:334)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbBaseline$2.call(DbBaseline.java:135)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbBaseline$2.call(DbBaseline.java:112)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:75)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbBaseline.baseline(DbBaseline.java:112)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:990)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:971)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1464)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:971)
```

...

I thought that flyway would be able to handle this situation based on the following:

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#parallel

Shouldn't a flyway instance detect that the schema version table is locked and move onto the next schema?

Is there a setting that can ensure the schema version is locked or is this a bug?

The OracleTable class locks the table in exclusive mode.  Should it add the NOWAIT clause and handle any resulting Oracle exception?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. We test this with every build and the behavior without NOWAIT is the one we desired (block until lock is released). If you can reliably reproduce this or see a clear mistake in our code, then please by all means do file a bug with the necessary details in the issue tracker.

Comment: In my case both flyway instances are attempting to run the same migrations.  Say the first flyway is waiting for the second flyway, which is in the process of migrating V1.0.0 to schema FOO.  It appears the first flyway attempts to migrate V1.0.0 after the second is finished and has unlocked the table, causing the unique constraint violation.  It seems that it should check before migrating as it normally does.